# pointing to my username dir

Tags: cygwin

Is it possible to set your home directory /home/username to point to the contents in your Windows user folder C:\Users\Username. Sort of like a make the path /home/username a softlink to C:\Users\Username. I am interested in doing this because I access this machine with SSH often and I always have to move to the /cygdrive.. complicated path...

Ted.

Comment: let me know below if I misinterpreted the question.

Comment: For anyone else finding this question, a more up to date answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494658/how-can-i-change-my-cygwin-home-folder-after-installation

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a soft link, you could change your Cygwin home directory in `/etc/passwd`.

Also, the `/cygdrive` profix can be changed, e.g. to `/mnt`, or even just `/`, so that `C:` can be accessed as `/c`. See http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#cygdrive.

Answer (score 1):

use..

```
 ln -s /home/username /your/windows/home
```

to create a symbolic link.

Comment: +1 I suggest that you `mv /home/username /home/username.bak` first, just in case you later regret this change.

Comment: I guess the most refined question would be .. can you have a soft link for a home directory?

Comment: you can also set the user home directory in /etc/passwd

Answer (score 0):

As an admin:

```
mkpasswd -l -p /cygwin/c/Users > /etc/passwd
```